# Scrolling JFXPanel with JScrollPane or overriding JFXPanel's scrollbar appearance

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a few related problems concerning a graphically customized `JScrollPane` with a `JFXPanel` inside. The `JFXPanel`, instead of growing to fit its contents and being scrollable with the scroll pane, creates its own uncustomized scroll bar alongside the customized one. It also fails to break long words in places where it would break sentences up:

[image]

Without the first line of text there would be no horizontal scrollbar. The long "word" lacking whitespace makes it fail at word wrapping. Lines 2-3 do what is expected and desired. And of course too many lines of text cause it to create a vertical bar.

Basically I need to

- Make the `JFXPanel` always grow to its maximum size, overflowing into GUI [hammerspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerspace) instead of creating a scrollbar, or otherwise disable its scrollbars allowing the `JScrollpane` to handle it

OR

- Customize the drawing for a `JFXPanel` scrollbar to make it look like the current custom scrollbar.
- and in both cases fix the wordwrap and make horizontal scrolling impossible

I'm new to JFX and don't know where to start attempting either or which approach would be better.

Comment: Why do you need to use Swing with JavaFX?

Comment: As noted above I know next to nothing about JFX. I already have the swing GUI working exactly as I want it, minus an small part that benefits from the fully functioning CSS a JFXPanel offers. So I have the choice of making these two work together, reverting to swing only and abandoning the CSS features, or switching entirely to JFX. I estimate the first choice will take a few hours, the second a few minutes, and the third a few weeks of remaking something I already have.  Even if I do redo it all in JFX, I'll be back here sometime next month asking how to customize the scrollbars anyway.